# How to fix Flask Blueprint Error - No Module Found

Tags: python, flask

I've looked at help guides and so forth but I still cannot seem to get Flask Blueprints working.

Here is my structure

```
root /
config.py
   |app/
        | __init__.py
        | user_auth/

              | __init__.py
              | app.py
              | routes.py
```

In the app/**init**.py file, it is the following

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

from .user_auth.routes import user_auth


app.register_blueprint(user_auth, url_prefix="")
```

From the user_auth **init**.py file is

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'trial'

from user_auth import routes, models
```

This is the user_auth/routes.py file

```
from user_auth import app, db
from flask_login import login_required
from user_auth.forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm
from flask import request, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, Blueprint
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse
from flask_login import logout_user

from flask_login import current_user, login_user
from user_auth.models import User


from flask import Blueprint
user_auth = Blueprint('user_auth', __name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', title='Welcome')


@app.route('/register', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def register():

... (Other paths)
```

I am running Windows and used the following command

```
set FLASK_APP=app
```

I then use

```
flask run
```

When I try to run, it says the following:

```
Error: While importing "app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "...\root\app\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .user_auth.routes import user_auth
  File "...\root\app\user_auth\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from user_auth import routes, models
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'user_auth'
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Why is there 2 different Flask app defined ? One in `app/init.py` and ont in `app/user_auth/init.py` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all files in  `app/user_auth/` like the `init.py` and `routes.py` that you mentionned up there, you nede either to access the package with

- absolute import : `from root.app.user_auth`
- relative import : `from ..user_auth`

Then i'd suggest to not use the same name for more than 1 think, here `user_auth` is both a package name, and the the variable name of you blueprint

Change like

```
 # routes.py
user_auth_bp = Blueprint('user_auth', __name__)

# app/__init__.py
from .user_auth.routes import user_auth_bp
app.register_blueprint(user_auth_bp, url_prefix="")
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped but I have another issue. The question is linked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64736778/how-to-use-flask-login-with-blueprints